# Нужно, чтобы проект собирался каждый раз. Как так сделать?

Tags: visual-studio

Мне нужно, чтобы сборка проекта происходила каждый раз перед запуском программы из Visual Studio. То есть, при нажатии CTRL + F5 сборка должна происходить каждый раз, даже если изменений в коде не было.
Есть ли такая настройка? Это должно быть именно в проекте, а не в общем в VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в проект добавить `post-build` событие, которое, к примеру, будет обновлять метку времени одного файла из проекта:

```xml
<PostBuildEvent>
  <Command>copy /b filename.ext +,,</Command>
</PostBuildEvent>
```

Таким образом для VS (`msbuild`) этот файл (`filename.ext`) все время будет выглядеть как измененный.